# Getting strange output from Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am attempting to print to the terminal in Python using the following code obtained from similar questions:

```
cmd = 'test'
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

However doing this gives me the output of:

```
b''
```

How can I fix my code to properly output to the terminal?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I fix my code to properly output to the terminal? All other questions / solutions seem to indicate that this is the correct way to do so.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: "test", or whatever value I assign to the variable cmd

Comment: The you should use `print("test")`. Your code is doing something absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: Just for the record: feel free to accept my answer; in case it turned out helpful in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! Will show my gratitude ;-)

Comment: Appreciate it! Sorry for the relatively dumb question haha. I swear my questions aren't usually that bad, I am just new to Python (coming from Obj C / iOS dev)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the man pages:

```
test - check file types and compare values
```

A program to test files. And when you run it on the command line .. it simply prints nothing (because this command works on the file names provided to it; and as you are not passing any arguments, it simply has nothing to say)

And that output there tells you that (where b'' means: empty array of byte octets; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) for details on that).

So the real answer here: before you start wondering what a tool does when you call it within python ... run it directly on the shell.

Comment: The link I am providing there ... explains exactly that b'' part.

Comment: So you have no clue what you are doing and expect other people to explain it to you? Your **own** code is using sub process to start a *sub process* to run the command that **you** are passing to it. That command is named test. And Assuming that you are using a Linux system, I explained to you what "test" is about.